# xslt change writing-mode to FA is metadata language is FA

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I'm working in the xsl-file "generate_document_structure.xsl" and a'm not so familiar with this older structure.

My goal in this is to change the writing-mode from lr-tb to rl-tb if the language in the METADATA is FA or AR.

Below a cleaned-up piece of code from the ouputfolder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fctdcl>    
        <publicationinfo dclselection="SelectedNode">
            <props>
                <attrblock type="1toN" name="language">
                    <attrlist>
                        <attrdesc id="1" name="language"/>
                    </attrlist>
                    <attrrec>
                        <attrval id="1">Default</attrval>
                    </attrrec>
                </attrblock>
            </props>
        </publicationinfo>
```

It is a big guess for my how to make the connection to the METADATA if the language is FA. in other words, i'm looking for the wright xpath to the METADATA and select the value of it.

i was thinking in the way like below:

```
<xsl:variable name="language">
    <xsl:value-of select="//*[contains(@class, ' /FCTDocuments/metadata/@language ')]/@content"></xsl:value-of>
 </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$language = 'FA'">
             <xsl:attribute name="writing-mode">rl-tb</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me in this

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make sense of what you want.  Is the element `METADATA` or 'metadata`?  Please provide a sample of an `@language` from a real document so that we can see the XML where it's used.

Answer (score 0):

@Toni,

I made some steps with it.

Below my current file.

```
<xsl:template name="FoT_page-sequence_ContentSequence">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not(/FCTDocuments/chapter)">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="ContentSequence">
      <xsl:call-template name="AddHyphenationToSequence"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="chapter_header_footer_without_config"/>
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" xsl:use-attribute-sets="XSL_Content">
        <fo:block id="last-page"/>
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:for-each select="/FCTDocuments/chapter">
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="ContentSequence" initial-page-number="auto-odd" writing-mode="rl-tb"> <!---->
        <xsl:if test="/FCTDocuments/@RSKM-ProductType = 'MM' ">
          <xsl:attribute name="initial-page-number">
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" xsl:use-attribute-sets="XSL_Content">
          <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::chapter) = 0">
            <xsl:if test="$DEBUG = 'true'">
              <!-- write debug informations -->
              <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>DEBUG: Starting Content creation</xsl:text>
        </xsl:comment>
            </xsl:if>
            <fo:block>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="DOCUMENTNAME">
                <xsl:value-of select="/FCTDocuments/Cover/CoverTitle"/>
              </fo:marker>
              <fo:marker marker-class-name="DOCUMENTINFO">
                <xsl:value-of select="$DOCUMENTINFO"/>
              </fo:marker>
            </fo:block>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::chapter) = 0">
            <fo:block id="last-page"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

As we zoom in at the codepart below i added the attribure "writing-mode" in the fo:page-sequence. And after a test it worked fine, But this must only happend when the language is FA

So no i need to make a choose of if statement like `test="/FCTDocuments/@RSKM-Language = 'FA'">`

how do I manage that if the lang-attribute is FA

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="ContentSequence" initial-page-number="auto-odd" writing-mode="rl-tb"> <!---->
    <xsl:if test="/FCTDocuments/@RSKM-ProductType = 'MM' ">
      <xsl:attribute name="initial-page-number">
        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: This does not look like an answer. To clarify a question, you should edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You initially said you were looking for the right XPath to select your METADATA/metadata, which is why I was asking to see the language code in your source XML.

I am guessing that this is what you want:

```
<xsl:if test="/FCTDocuments/@RSKM-Language = 'FA'">
  <xsl:attribute name="writing-mode">rl</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

You can then omit the `writing-mode` property on the `fo:page-sequence` since the default `writing-mode` value is `lr-tb`.

Comment: Thanx a thousand times , that did the trick whitout the "tb"!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked, but please also 'accept' the answer.